# On a banking website should i use DRUPAL or WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress, drupal

I have a meeting and i need to know whats the good on working with "DRUPAL" building a banking website i need brief response because i've never used "DRUPAL" but instead of that i'm using "wordpress".

Comment: Wordpress & Drupal are content manangement systems. If your banking website is going to provide static information only, use wordpress as you're friendly with it. There's no need to switch to Drupal.

Transactions & account information systems need a Database server(MySQL:InnoDB) & back-end code(go for PHP 7.1).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @BhaskarChoudhary but as you see the client needs to know further information about Drupal which i don't know also the banking website will not be static, so .. and the client request Drupal and i need to stand and talk about that CMS

Comment: For banking? Use neither IMHO. Never mind the security, they could be busy websites and will therefore be way too too slow with Drupal or Wordpress.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library, tutorial, book, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. If you cannot find a resource that does what you want it to, then you'll need to write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’ve never used Drupal before you will find it challenging to build a banking website.. especially if there’s going to be online transactions etc.. you will need a lot of custom module development..and Drupal has a steep learning curve but if your client will give you time to learn then go for it and build it in Drupal.. Drupal is used a lot to build large e-commerce sites so one of Drupals advantages is that it’s security is secure.

There’s loads of online tutorials to help you
Buildamodule and drupalize me are good

If you already know WordPress maybe that’s your best bet.. just make sure your site and plugins are always up to date to avoid vulnerabilities as security is going to be one of the most important features if you are dealing with customer data etc..

Answer (score 0):

Use Drupal.  There's a reason you don't see many banking websites in WordPress.  The security thread alone of using that CMS make it a hard sell for any of the bank's internal security team members.  Its not that Drupal is inherently more secure than WordPress, its that the attack vectors into WordPress are much greater.  If you're having a vendor do this make sure you have a support agreement in place so they update the CMS for you, or get on a CMS managed hosting platform that can do this automatically for you.  Drupal is also very fast with the right caching tools in place.  Its why the Olympics website ran Drupal and didn't have any performance issues.